# Use numba jitclass as a parameter in numba jit function

Tags: python, cuda, gpu, numba

I'm using numba 0.46.0 and I want to pass an object of my class to my function as an argument and run this function on my GPU with CUDA.
If I want to use a simple Python object (like `int`), I use something like this:

```py
from numba import jit, cuda
from numba.types import void, int32

@jit(void(int32), target='cuda')
def f(int_object):
    pass

f(123)
```

And this works fine. Now I try to do the same thing with a class:

```py
from numba import jit, cuda
from numba,types import void

@jitclass([])
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

@jit(void(MyClass), target='cuda')
def f(MyClass_object):
    pass
```

And this fails with `NotImplementedError` without any comments. I also tried to compile this in a lazy way:

```py
@jit(target='cuda')
def f(MyClass_object):
    pass

f(MyClass())
```

This failes with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/cuda/dispatcher.py", line 42, in __call__
    return self.compiled(*args, **kws)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py", line 801, in __call__
    cfg(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py", line 537, in __call__
    sharedmem=self.sharedmem)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py", line 604, in _kernel_call
    self._prepare_args(t, v, stream, retr, kernelargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py", line 715, in _prepare_args
    raise NotImplementedError(ty, val)
NotImplementedError: (instance.jitclass.MyClass#7f983418fc88<>, <numba.jitclass.boxing.MyClass object at 0x7f983416ca10>)
```

Can I use a jitclass object as a jit function argument? If yes, what is wrong in the example above?

UPD:
By the way, I have checked this with numpy arrays:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, cuda
from numba.types import void

@jit(void(np.ndarray), target='cuda')
def f1(ndarray_object):
    pass
# Fails with NotImplementedError with no comments

@jit(target='cuda')
def f2(ndarray_object):
    pass

a = np.asarray([])
f2(a) # Executes with no errors, only a warning about autojit
```

Why this works with numpy, but doesn't work with my class? Why this works with numpy in lazy mode (f2), but does not work with given signatures (f1)?

Comment: classes are not supported in Numba CUDA kernels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the relevant [documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/jitclass.html#limitations) (Numba 0.47 at the time of writing):

> Support for jitclasses are available on CPU only. (Note: Support for
>   GPU devices is planned for a future release.)